# Why wont javascript work after being loading through ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a main page with this script on it to load status.html into my info-box_main div

```
window.onload = ajax_req('scripts/home/php/status.html', 'info-box_main');
```

The status.html file that is loaded looks like this.

```
<div id="status_update">
    <form id="status_form" method="post" action="/scripts/home/php/statusUpdate.php/">
        <textarea name="status_update" placeholder="Type Link update here. " id="status_field" ></textarea>
        <input type='submit' value='post'/>
    </form>
</div>

<div id='status-box'>
    <button onclick="myFunction('Harry Potter','Wizard')">Try it</button>

    <script>
        function myFunction(name,job){
            alert("Welcome " + name + ", the " + job);
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

---

ajax_req function

```
function ajax_req(file_location, document_element)
{
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }                                 //ajax update request
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById(document_element).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",  file_location ,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Everything works fine except for the javascript. I get an error that says the function is not defined when I try to click the button. Any help would be awesome! This is just test javascript... not the actual javascript I need

Comment: Show `ajax_req` function

Comment: What is this `ajax_req()` function?  How does it work?

Comment: I added the function. Sorry about that.

Comment: @user2930376 - Since you tagged jQuery, you can just use `$.ajax()` to load files. But the scripts will still not be run though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `innerHTML` property of an element to a string of HTML content including `<script>` tags does **not** run the script content in any browser I know of.

If you are indeed using jQuery, there's absolutely no reason to code up your own ajax facility, and the jQuery `.load()` method will handle script content for you.

```
$('#info-box_main').load('scripts/home/php/status.html');
```

Comment: How would I change that. I am not that familiar with ajax. function ajax_req is derived from tutorials online to load the entire file.

Comment: @user2930376 it has nothing really to do with ajax. Browsers simply ignore `<script>` content when you set the `.innerHTML` property.

Comment: hmmmm. That makes since. Is there any way to force it?

Comment: @user2930376 well jQuery and other libraries pull the `<script>` blocks out and then hand them to `eval()` (when appropriate).

Comment: Or.... Is there a way I can import the contents of the document without setting the innerHTML property?

Comment: @user2930376 sorry - I just noticed you tagged the post with "jQuery". If you are using that, then you can just the library do everything.

Comment: @user2930376 - Actually, AJAX isn't intended for loading pages with scripts attached. You shouldn't really do this. You can either use `$.getScript` to load the scripts independently, or just load everything at the beginning.

Comment: Just put whatever you have in your `<script>` tag in your main .js file which you are using to load the html anyway.

Comment: @DarkAshelin well there are situations where that's inconvenient, though I do basically agree that it's an *undesirable* thing to do. If the content is dynamically generated, it may be that there are some hacks that require some client side action to alter the HTML depending on client-side state information.

Comment: @Pointy to be honest that can all be taken care of through checks in the main javascript file, and possibly variables that are filled in through the php function.

Comment: @user2930376 Online tutorials are often outdated and plain wrong. I'd use [the Mozilla reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) to read up at first, and check Douglas Crockford's video's on youtube.

@ Pointy Btw browsers don't ignore script tags in the body. It's just that there's only a function declaration inside the script tag. You need to invoke it ;)

Comment: @DarkAshelin I cannot do that. I need to have a for loop running inside the script tag on the page. The $.load() method works AWESOME! Thank you!!!

Comment: @KemHeyndels no that's not what I said - it's not `<script>` tags in the `<body>` that are a problem, it's `<script>` tags in dynamic content that you're adding to the DOM by assigning it to the `.innerHTML` of some DOM node. That's when `<script>` tags are ignored.

Comment: Using the above method(.load) comments out my php code... How can I avoid this?

Comment: @user2930376 ??? "comments out my php code"?  I have no idea what that means; `.load()` makes an ajax call more or less the same way your own code does. Use the browser developer tools to make sure that the HTTP request/response don't have errors etc.

Comment: @user2930376 also your URL has a `.html` extension. What PHP code are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you include it in a script in the header.

```
window.onload = function () {
    $('#info-box_main').load('scripts/home/php/status.html');
};
```

Alternative solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#info-box_main').load('scripts/home/php/status.html', function () {
        $("#status-box").bind("click", myFunction);
        // Seperate javascript from html, and only bind event once hmtl has loaded.
    });
};
function myFunction (name,job) {
    alert("Welcome " + name + ", the " + job);
}
```

If you stick to inlining your javascript, I'd consider putting the script tag before any other tag (like the button tag in your example) that references values in the script tag. That way you're sure your script tag has been evaluated before its values are being referenced.

Comment: That was just an example. The script I need to work absolutely has to run in the body of the document from the status.html file.

Comment: How about adding the script to the top of the body? That way it always runs first.